# How can I fix a site's Document folder being at 100% of % of Parent?

Tags: sharepoint-online, storage

I'm getting errors trying to move some files into a SharePoint site of ours, and when I check how it's set up, I'm seeing the below, [image]

We've a total of 25TB space available, of which just over 2 has been used, but the Documents folder shows up as 100% for % of Parent.  I don't really understand what the "Parent" is here.

I hope there's an easy fix, but if not I'll contact MS' support tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

The **"% of Parent"** column indicates the amount of storage that an item takes up relative to the rest of the items in that scope (i.e. that item's parent). In terms of the **"% of Parent"**, it's the % of the parent's directory used. Drilling into the document folder will show the breakdown of usage scoped to that folder. The **"% of Parent"** column will show which files or folders are using the most space proportionally to each other only relative to that folder.

**You can continue to save documents until the total usage of the site reaches the site collection's quota.** Looking at which folders and items are using the most space (via the **"% of Site Quota"** column) can help you find and remove large documents and folders if you ever hit the site storage quota. The **"% of parent"** column can then help you choose which specific files to remove.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue reported by the users. Agree with @EchoDu_MSFT, "**% of Parent**" in column storage metrics indicates the amount of storage utilized by a Component (Site/List/Library/Folder/File) with respect to total storage of parent(Site/Library/Folder).

> In your case if you drill down to **Documents**, "% of Parent" column will
> show the percentage of storage used by each file/folder relative to
> **Documents** library. You can ignore warnings and continue to use library.

**By default, you do not have any limits for storage at a site level and you have 25 TB storage quota allotted at site collection level.**

However if you want you can set/manage site quota at site level as well, refer below article for more information.

Click [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-access-storage-metrics-reports-on-a-sharepoint-site/)!